# moving from NetworkManager to systemd-resolved

Tags: vpn, dns, fedora, systemd

Can someone explain how systemd-resolved works? After reinstall to fedora 33 from fedora 30, I cannot use obsolete SNX VPN. The root cause is that DNS records are not updated. Before when I started snx vpn, new dns records appeared in /etc/resolv.conf, which content looked like:

```
cat resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver A.B.C.D
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search <some urls>
```

now this file contains this:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# etc.
```

and its content does not react to vpn being started.

It seems to be, that some bridging from NetworkManager to systemd-resolved is not working. Arch wiki mentions need to install `systemd-resolvconf` for legacy programs, but this is not available for fedora.

Questions:

1. how to make it work automatically? When I start `snx` vpn, before there was (probably, no idea what happened actually) some communication with NetworkManager resulting in regenerated resolv.conf. How to fix fedora 33, so that snx still updates list of nameservers and search patterns.
2. if that is not possible for whichever reason, how to manually add dns records now, ideally using some script not to have to click it on some gui.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after searching a lot for how systemd-routed should be used and having found *close to nothing*, and regarding VPNs in general I found some *500 LOC convoluted bash scripts* to get it working, I think, the best solution is sadly the same as with SELinux. Unless you got some proper training using sacred study materials and a lot of time to spend on it, pure mortals have single solution: turn it off.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu

works equally with fedora. After disabling as shown, VPN works as it used to.

If anyone has some sacred material, or whatever from where I can learn how to use this properly without having to turn anything off and use benefits of this, please, pretty please, share.